# I want to replace the words in description with dataframe from my column and add it to my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, regexp-replace

I want to replace the name and age in description with the data in my table.

```
data = {'name' : ['Max','Jim'],'Age':[32,44],'desc':''}
```

```
desc = "My name is <name> and my age is <age>."
```

Like this,

```
Output:
    name    Age desc
0   Max 32  My name is Max and my age is 32.
1   Jim 44  My name is Jim and my age is 44.
```

I have tried using np.where() and regex functions but still not getting expected results.
I'm using python version 3.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fully programmatic approach, you can use a regex:

```
import re

data = {'name' : ['Max','Jim'],'Age':[32,44],'desc':''}
desc = "My name is <name> and my age is <age>."

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

df['desc'] = df.apply(lambda row: re.sub(r'<(\w+)>',
                                         lambda m: str(row[m.group(1)]), desc),
                      axis=1)
```

Or with a list comprehension (assuming unique indices!):

```
df['desc'] = [re.sub(r'<(\w+)>', lambda m: str(df.loc[idx, m.group(1)]), desc)
              for idx in df.index]
```

Output:

```
  name  age                              desc
0  Max   32  My name is Max and my age is 32.
1  Jim   44  My name is Jim and my age is 44.
```

Of course a non-programmatic but much more efficient approach would have been:

```
df['desc'] = "My name is " + df['name'] + " and my age is " + df['age'] + "."
```

Comment: The 1st method worked exceptionally well for me, whereas 2nd one was quite slow. But thanks man saved my time or I was going to approach like 3rd method manually...!!!!!

Comment: If you don't have so many variables, the last method should be faster (to run, not to type!) ;)

Comment: actually i have lot of variables and different description with same idea so ya..no to 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

With single regex replacement for preparing `desc` (with placeholders), then - just string formatting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
f_desc = re.sub(r'<([^<>]+)>', r'{\1}', desc)
df['desc'] = df.apply(lambda r: f_desc.format(**r), axis=1)
```

---

```
  name  age                              desc
0  Max   32  My name is Max and my age is 32.
1  Jim   44  My name is Jim and my age is 44.
```

Comment: this also worked but it is taking lot of time. thanks for the code and new function

Comment: @RushabhNalawade "it is taking lot of time" - that sounds really doubdfull

Comment: bcoz my data is bit different and description has lot of variables and my data contains around 10 million rows...

Comment: @RushabhNalawade, that was not reflected by your initial question